# About totally umbilical hypersurfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Suppose $\tilde{M} \subset M$ is a hypersurface sitting inside a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. The second fundamental form of $M$ evaluated on $u,v \in T_pM$ is denoted $II(u,v)$ and defined as the normal component of $\tilde{\nabla}_UV$ for some extensions $U$ and $V$ of $u$ and $v$. Define $l(u,v)$ by the relation $II(u,v) = l(u,v)\nu$ for $\nu$ a fixed unit normal vector field of $M$ around $p$.

I recently came across the following exercice : The hypersurface $M$ is said to be *totally umbilical* if $l = fg$ for $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ and $g$ the restriction of the metric to $M$. It is asked to show that if $\dim M \geq 2$, then $f$ must be a constant.

The book says it is a consequence of the Gauss-Codazzi equation
$$\tilde{R}(x,y,u,\nu) = \nabla_xl(y,u) - \nabla_yl(x,u).$$
I tried playing around with this equation, taking traces hoping to find a Bianchi identity, but didn't have any success. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: The result could also be obtained using moving frames, if you're familiar with them.

Comment: @AaronS: can you please give a reference to the proof via moving frames method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) If $\widetilde{M}={\bf R}^{n+1}$, then from Codazzi, we have $$
x(f) g(y,z) - y(f) g(x,z) =0$$

If $y=z\perp x$, then $x(f)=0$ That is $f$ is **constant**

(2) If $\widetilde{M}$ is general, then we have an **counter example** : $\widetilde{M}=({\bf R}^2\times {\bf R},
G:=F(x_3)^2g_1(x_1,x_2)+ g_2(x_3)),\ M={\bf R}^2$ Here $g_i$ are
canonical metric on each factor

If $E_i$ is coordinate vector field, then $\nu :=E_3 $ are
orthonormal And $$ \Gamma_{13}^1 = \frac{1}{2} G^{11} \{ G_{11,3} + G_{13,1} -
G_{13,1} \} =  \frac{F_3 }{F} = \Gamma_{23}^2   $$
$$ \Gamma_{13}^2 = \frac{1}{2} G^{22} \{ G_{12,3} + G_{23,1} -
G_{13,2}\} =0 $$
So $$ l(E_1,E_1)=(\nabla_1 E_3, E_1)=F^2\Gamma_{13}^1 =FF_3= l
(E_2,E_2) $$
And $$ l (E_1,E_2)=(\nabla_1 E_3,E_2)= F^2\Gamma_{13}^2 = 0 $$
Hence $$ f:=\frac{F_3}{F} $$

Answer (score 0):

What about if the hypersurface is only $C^2$, so you cannot use Codazzi-Mainardi equations?